# Privileges List

Tags: support, privileges

Being new on this site, I'm slowly gaining more reputation and am unlocking new privileges (such as upvoting, commenting, etc.). On my account it tracks the next privilege that I'm progressing towards, but not the ones after (at least not to my knowledge).

My Question:

> Can someone provide me with a list of privileges that you gain and at the required reputation needed for each one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Math Help Center's [Privileges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page gives you a full list. If you're logged in, the dialog also shows the ones you've already earned with a green checkmark on the left side.

One way you can get to this dialog is by clicking the Help button, which is the one with the question mark second from the right side in the buttons list at the top right, as shown below

[image: List of buttons at the top right]

and then clicking the "Help Center" link which brings up a dialog where there's a Privileges section at the bottom of the middle column, as shown below

[image: Privileges section of the Help Center dialog]

You can then click the link to show the Privileges dialog.

Note the Help Center dialog also has links to many other pages which provide a lot of other useful information.

Comment: Also, one can reach this page by mouse only: from anywhere in Math.SE, click on your avatar/rep in top right to get to your activity page. Then click on the progress bar for the next privilege, click on "learn more" in the pop-up, and then at the top, where it says "Mathematics Stack Exchange > Help center > Privileges", click on Privileges

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to access this if you are logged in is through the achievements dialog.

[image]